# URI Prefix not supported

Tags: c#, wpf, soundplayer

I am trying to load and play a wave file using:

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Sounds/10meters.wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
```

With no success. I get a `System.NotSupportedException` :( see below.

```
System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   at System.Media.SoundPlayer.LoadSync()
   at System.Media.SoundPlayer.LoadAndPlay(Int32 flags)
   at System.Media.SoundPlayer.Play()
```

I looked over google and SO trying to find a solution, nothing worked. 
Playing the file with a direct path works fine

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"D:\Projects\MyAssembly\Sounds\10meters.wav");
simpleSound.Play();
```

I also checked MyAssembly content, the resource is there. 
Does `SoundPlayer` not support packing or there anything I am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pack://` URI scheme is specific to WPF, so non-WPF components don't know how to handle it... however, you can retrieve a stream for this resource, and pass it to the `SoundPlayer` constructor:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Sounds/10meters.wav");
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(sri.Stream);
simpleSound.Play();
```

Another option is to use the `MediaPlayer` class:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Sounds/10meters.wav");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(uri);
player.Play();
```

This class supports the `pack://` URI scheme

Comment: Good call on the stream constructor.

Comment: +1 thanks. `StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);` did not work as I am doing this from a dll file not the main exe application. MediaPlayer is too heavy for what I am doing :( Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean, "did not work"? You just need to add a reference to PresentationFramework. There's no way to access a resource with a pack URI independently from WPF, if that's what you're trying to do...

Comment: Damn me, completely forgot to reference PresentationFramework. Thanks a lot for the pointer

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thanks for the awesome answer. I tried both your solutions. Using StreamResourceInfo with SoundPlayer worked. But using MediaPlayer doesnot. No sound is played when I use MediaPlayer. Both solutions are referring to the exact same URI in my project. I tuned the MediaPlayer's volume to max and still cannot get any sound.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F1</kbd> is your friend (in VS 2010 at least):

> The string passed to the soundLocation parameter can be either a file path or a URL to a .wav file.

URIs are not URLs (unlike the other way around), this will not work. You could save the file to temporary folder on disk if you need to.