# How to use ResourceDictionary in DLL from ConsoleApp?

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

I have a DLL with a ResourceDictionary.
If i call this dict from WPF app, all will work correctly.
But if i call a dict from console app, i wiil get an error "The URI prefix s not recognized"

```
        ResourceDictionary res = new ResourceDictionary();
        try
        {
            res.Source = new Uri("ClassLibrary1;component/SomeDict.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            var l = res["SomeKey"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Try to specify *full* `Uri` (or how is it called): [click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8344595/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr now i have this error Invalid URI: invalid port.
I used this: res.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/SomeDict.xaml");
I try to add ResourceDictionary into ConsoleApp. When i call it i get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its need to configurate Uri. This articles will help in it.

http://www.yac.com.pl/mt.texts.wpf-tests-pack-uri-handling.en.html

http://compilewith.net/2009/03/wpf-unit-testing-trouble-with-pack-uris.html

[UriFormatException : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005398/uriformatexception-invalid-uri-invalid-port-specified)

I used this

```
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
{
    Application app = Application.Current;
}
```